# Building and running an executable jar of spock groovy scripts

Tags: gradle, groovy, spock, multi-module

I have a multi-module Gradle application:
root setting.gralde.kts:

```
include(
    ":common-config-qa",
    ":app-spock-tests",
)
```

the `common-config-qa` application contains

1. main spock-groovy code which sets up required data for the tests to be executed.
2. java util classes

the `app-spock-tests` contains spock-groovy code to run spock tests for multiple apps separated into each folder.

When I execute `./gradlew clean test` the tests are getting executed.
I tried to create an executable jar out of this project by specifying the following in the `build.gradle.kts` file under `common-config-qa` project:

```
application {
    mainClass.set("com.test.qa.CommonSpockSpec")
}

tasks.jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(mapOf("Implementation-Title" to project.name,
            "Implementation-Version" to project.version))
    }
}
```

Also included the plugin: `id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "7.1.2"` to create a shadow jar.

I included the same plugin on the other app.

The uber-jar is getting created but when I execute the command from the root folder:
`./gradlew jar common-config-qa/build/libs/common-config-qa-0.1-all.jar`: I am getting the error as

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'common-config-qa/build/libs/common-config-qa-0.1-all.jar' not found in root project 'root-spock-project'.
```

If I execute the same command from inside the folder `common-config-qa`, I am getting the error as:

```
* What went wrong:
Task 'build/libs/common-config-qa-0.1-all.jar' not found in root project 'common-config-qa'.
```

I would like to have a jar which I can use to execute the tests from command line. How can I get an executable jar for this application and its runs properly.

Comment: Could you please explain why you want to create an executable test jar? While it is not impossible, it is a bit complicated and normally not what you want. Have a look a https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-console-launcher

Comment: @LeonardBrünings The reason to have an executable jar is to `containerize` this app and deploy as containers. I tried the `console launcher` but it did not work as I expected. In the interest of time, I am copying the complete code in container and running the docker image. This is working for now.

Comment: Containerizing the app is fine, but why do you want to containerize the tests, are they some kind of acceptance tests that have to run in a k8s environment?

Comment: @LeonardBrünings yes thats the plan. To run these spock tests as scheduled jobs inside the K8S env on a daily basis and view the results. Right now instead of running them as jar, I am executing the same using `gradle clean test` command. Its working thought but has other issues. I opened another question for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74081050/parsing-through-spock-test-results?noredirect=1#comment130802318_74081050