# Parsing through spock test results

Tags: java, spock

All, I have a test suite developed using spock-groovy framework. The output of this is a set of html files. I have a requirement to run this test as part of a docker container on cloud. After the test execution, I would like to get a summary of the test results and also a link of the html files to view the details of these results.
Is there a library already available for parsing the test results for spock? How can I get this done using Java from the app running in the container?

Build tool: `gradle`.

I created the docker container using the Dockerfile. The entrypoint for this docker container is a shell script which sets required variables and then executes the command `gradle clean test...`.

Few issues I am trying to resolve:

1. The container is able to execute the tests but I am unable to get the results out of that container. I am trying the approach as mentioned in point 2 below to get the results out of the container.
2. I have added `def cleanupSpec() {....}` method where I am trying to send a notification to slack channel. As I see from inside the container, this step is not getting executed. When I run this app locally, I am able to see the notification being sent.

Comment: Please give us more information about your setup, such as what build tool you are using to build and run the tests. Is it Gradle, Maven, Ant. or something else?

Comment: I would suggest to do a `reporTest` task in gradle that depends on the `test` task and does whatever you need, e.g., zip up the results and upload them somewhere or send a slack message, and then just run that task.